# C recursive function won't return true

Tags: c, recursion, return

I have a search function which employs recursion to perform a binary search of an array, `values[]`, for a `value`:

```
int recurseSearch(int value, int values[], int min, int max) {

    if (value > values[max] || min > max) return 1;

    int midpoint = (max+min)/2;

    if (values[midpoint] > value)
        //search in left
        recurseSearch(value, values, min, midpoint);

    else if (values[midpoint] < value)
        //search in right
        recurseSearch(value, values, midpoint, max);

    else if (values[midpoint] == value)
        return 0;

    else 
        return 2;

    return 3;
}
```

The code that calls this simply calls `recurseSearch(value, values, 0, n);`
For the sake of verifying, I will set `values[5]` to equal `{3, 11, 32, 54, 66}`, `value` to be `3` (i.e. this should return 0), and `n` to therefore be `5`.

So this gets called: `recurseSearch(3, values, 0, 5);`

Now I would expect this to eventually return, and print, `0`, since `3` is indeed in the array. Upon debugging everything is going well up until the `midpoint` is 0, and therefore `values[midpoint] == value` is true, and so the `return 0` line should run. However, what happens instead is that it does, but then comtrol aparently moves to the end (closing `}`) of the function, but then moves back up and runs the `return 3;` on line (here) 21.

I cannot understand why the `return 0` statement doesn't just return out of the function and why the `return 3` doesn't run at all

---

N.B. This problem is solved by removing the `return 3;` line, however this causes clang to complain, and the command for running (`make`) that I'm using, *fatally* have a hissy-fit, which I would much rather avoid

Comment: You could perhaps avoid the hissy-fit by setting a return value at each conditional, and then use a single return to return that value.  The code would also benefit from having fewer returns within it.

Comment: In your code `return 3` is the catch all. When the child function returns 0 to the parent caller, the parent caller proceeds to the end of the `if...elseif..else` block and ends up returning 3.

Comment: However, removing `return 3` causes end of function without return. Again, when the child returns, the parent proceeds to the end of the function. You are also neglecting to handle the return value of the child. Shouldn't you return to the grandparent what the child return to the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not looked carefully at your code so there might be other bugs in it, but it sounds like you want the return value from the deepest recursive call to be passed up the stack all the way to the caller.  In that case, you would remove the `return 3;` and simply return the value of each the recursive call you are making:

```
int recurseSearch(int value, int values[], int min, int max) {

    if (value > values[max] || min > max) return 1;

    int midpoint = (max+min)/2;

    if (values[midpoint] > value)
        //search in left
        return recurseSearch(value, values, min, midpoint);

    else if (values[midpoint] < value)
        //search in right
        return recurseSearch(value, values, midpoint, max);

    else if (values[midpoint] == value)
        return 0;

    else 
        return 2;
}
```

The way you originally wrote your code, the return values from the recursive calls were being ignored entirely, and the `return 3;` statement would be executed instead.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response; is there any way, then, to fix the compiler complaining (sometimes fatally) that *"control may reach end of non-void function"*?

Comment: You have to make sure that every code path ends in a return statement, so there is no way for the function to execute without encountering a return statement.  If you compile the code I posted in my answer, the compiler should not give you that error.  Did you try compiling it?  Note that I added `return` before each call to `recurseSearch`.  When you see that error, you need to look at your code and think about every possible way it could execute, and make sure it always reaches a `return` statement.

Comment: So it seems we have four cases: (1) `values[midpoint] > value`, (2) `values[midpoint] < value`, (3) `values[midpoint] == value` and (4) "the moon is made of green cheese".

Comment: @joe_young: Remove the `else` after every `if` that `return`s.

Comment: @n.m. case 4 should never happen in real life, but I chose to just make minimal modifications to the OP's code I am not taking responsibility for it being totally free of bugs.

Comment: Per @EOF's comment, just remove the final `else` and leave a `return 2` at the bottom of the function.  That final `else` does not change the semantics of the code since `return 2` will always be called at that point anyway, and its removal eliminates the compiler-doesn't-realize-it's-never-reached "moon is made of green cheese" return case.

Comment: To make the first and second conditions false, is easy. But I wonder what combinations will make all 3 conditions false.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer; it turns out that it was the `return`s before calling `recurseSearch()` each time that I needed